# Разбор числительных по составу

Tags: числительные, морфемика, число

Нигде не могу найти достоверной информации, что же такое *-дцать*, *-надцать* в числительных *одиннадцать* - *девятнадцать*, *двадцать* и *тридцать*?

В некоторых источниках указано, что это суффиксы. Но как тогда быть со словами:

```
 двенадцать = дв/е/надцать
 двадцать = дв/а/дцать
```

Получается, что суффикс следует после окончания? Да и какое же это окончание, если ни в одной словоформе оно не меняется:

```
двенадцат/и
двенадцать/ю
```

В отличие от, например, сложных числительных:

```
пять/десят/
пять/ю/десять/ю
```

А вот на соединительные гласные морфемы *-е-* и *-а-* похожи. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Совсем недавно был разноброд по этому вопросу даже в школьных учебниках. Ленинградская и московская школы не сошлись во мнениях. Бабайцева числит. 11-19 относила к сложным,кстати, Розенталь тоже, предпочитая архаичный корень -дцать признавать за полноценный.

В учебнике Н.С.Валгиной в числительных части «надцать» и «дцать» являются не корнем, а суффиксом.

В  учебнике  для 6 класса М.М.Разумовской сообщается: «Количественные и порядковые числительные по своему строению делятся на три группы: простые: четыре, четырнадцать, тридцатый; сложные: пятьдесят, пятьсот, стотысячный; составные (состоят из двух или нескольких слов).

Такую точку зрения встречаем и в учебниках Т.А.Ладыженской, М.Т.Баранова, П.А.Леканта и других. В пособии Академии наук РФ «Грамматика русского языка» в параграфе 1367 сообщается: «Простые числительные – это слова с простой основой – немотивированные и суффиксальные: два, пять, десять, сорок, сто, сколько, столько,пятнадцать, тридцать; сложные числительные – это слова со сложной основой: шестьдесят, восемьсот».

Далее в учебнике М.М.Разумовской говорится: «У сложных количественных числительных при склонении изменяются обе части: двести, двумястами, о двухстах». Действительно, это неоспоримое явление при классификации числительных. В сложных числительных наблюдается два корня и оба изменяются. В числительных на «-надцать» и «-дцать» при склонении изменяется только окончание, корень слова не меняется.

двенадцать = дв/е/надцать

двадцать = дв/а/дцать

```
 Получается, что суффикс следует после окончания? Да и какое 
  же это       окончание, если ни в одной словоформе оно не меняется:
 А вот на соединительные гласные морфемы -е- и -а- похожи
```

Мне нравится Ваша логика.Осталось чуть додумать.Если двенадцать-простое числительное, образованное способом аффиксации, то -Е-тоже суффикс, т.е. два суффикса подряд. Произошло переразложение: было окончание жен.рода, стало суффиксом, потеряв способность изменяться при склонении.Но другие учёные относят -Е- тоже к интерфиксам. И это тоже оправдано.

Двадцать-сложное, образованное сложением корней с помощью интерфикса.-Е- интерфикс, соединит.гласная.

Только не пят/**и**/десять/ю, а пять**/ю** /десять/ю.

В сложных словах так бывает, что два окончания, и две приставки бывает(загранпогрузка);

Comment: У Тихонова две/на/дцать.. Есть мнение, что на - приставка.

Comment: Потрясающий ответ!

Comment: *Потрясающий ответ!*  - Людмила, мне остаётся только присоединиться к ДеNiZz'у, хотя от вас ничего иного и не ждал. **Вопрос** Зачем всё это, если более или менее известно происхождение подобных числительных? "Две на дцать" = "две на десять" = "две (штуки) сверху десяти". Ну все же прозрачно без этих заморочек, в общем-то. В вообще, "На" - это предлог )))

Comment: *было окончание жен.рода*, - разве? А почему тогда одиннадцать - мужского?  Я всегда считал, что "две" - исторически это шутка двойственного числа, а не грамматического рода.

Comment: Вы правы  в том, что это создаёт путаницу в головах учеников и наших. Вот когда пошли эти разные школы, пошёл разговор, что на язык нужно смотреть как на современное явление, а в современном русском сложные числительные при склонении меняют окончание, ведь это сложение слов, а не основ, а -Е- не меняется, значит, оно уже не окончание слова, а суффикс простого слова, потому что с помощью этой единицы образуются другие слова. В школе придерживаются этой версии, а в серьёзной науке по-прежнему два мнения.

Comment: Помните "на двунадесяти языках"? Вот тогда ещё склонялось

Comment: А что, род у сущ. и прилагательных двойственного числа отменяется?Двенадцать в старославянском выглядело так:дъве(=ять)надеся(=юс малый)те(=ять), а в древнерусском-дъванадесяте. Это сращение слов две(единицы), предлога на и формы местного пад. ед.числа от десять, редуцированного при произношении впоследствии в дцать: дс-тс-ц

Comment: *А что, род у сущ. и прилагательных двойственного числа отменяется?* - А, ну да. Сам не понял, чего сказал. ))) Спасибо.

Comment: *Помните "на двунадесяти языках"?* - Ну да. Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: *Вот когда пошли эти разные школы, пошёл разговор, что на язык нужно смотреть как на современное явление?* - Я в эти споры синхронистов и диахронистов не влезаю. Для меня и то и другое - инструмент, прибор, линейка измерительная. И как любой прибор он годится для производства  тех или иных измерений. Каждый своих. Все зависит от цели. Идея забивать гвозди микроскопом, увы, не нова. Вот это я и вижу - с Ваших слов - в том, что твориться в головах учеников.

Answer (score 3):

> Нигде не могу найти достоверной информации, что же такое *-дцать,
>   -надцать* в числительных *одиннадцать - девятнадцать, двадцать* и *тридцать*?

"[**Русская грамматика**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1032-1040.html)" подойдёт?

> § 1032. В суффиксальных количественных числительных *одиннадцать,
>   двенадцать* и далее, вплоть до *девятнадцать*, мотивированных
>   количественными числительными, называющими числа первого десятка,
>   выделяется **суф.** ***-надцать…*** В словах *двенадцать* и *тринадцать*
>   основа мотивирующего слова выступает с наращением за счет финали,
>   совпадающей с флексией им. п. (*три-*) и им. п. жен. р. (*две-*)
>   мотивирующего числительного; в остальных случаях (*одиннадцать,
>   четырнадцать, пятнадцать* и далее) – без наращения.
>
> В числительных *двадцать* и *тридцать*, мотивированных
>   числительными *два* и *три* и обозначающих количество десятков, равное
>   числу, названному мотивирующим словом, выделяется **суф.** ***-дцать***…
>   Основа мотивирующего слова выступает в этих словах с наращением за
>   счет финали, совпадающей с флексией им. п. (*три-*) и им. п. муж. и
>   сред. р. (*два-*) мотивирующего числительного...
>
> Примечание. Исторически **суф.** ***-дцать*** и ***-надцать***
>   представляют собой изменившиеся в звучании слово *десять* и предложное
>   сочетание *на десять*.

===

*Дв-**е**-надцать, тр-**и**-надцать, дв-**а**-дцать...*

> А вот на соединительные гласные морфемы *-е-* и *-а-* похожи.

Такие элементы Тихонов (и ряд других лингвистов) называет ***интерфиксами***.

См. его *"Словообразовательный словарь русского языка" (М., 1990)* 
**§ 8 б**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за интересные выкладки!

Comment: Можете написать, что это за книга/работа Тихонова?

Comment: Виноват. В черновике ответа у меня была ссылка, Когда переносил ответ сюда, эту ссылку потерял. Сейчас ответ поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Это числительное образовалось сращением слов "один на десяте" (то есть один свыше десяти). По такому же принципу образованы и все другие числительные от 11 до 19. Кстати, это объясняет и почему из всех числительных этого ряда только 11 пишется с двумя "н": ведь только в этом числительном сходятся два "н" – от слова один и от предлога на.

> Этимологический словарь русского языка. — СПб.: ООО "Виктория плюс". Крылов   Г. А.. 2004.